# Using the field calculator to replace the character in QGIS

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, replace, regular-expression

How to use the field calculator to replace the character `-` in part of the values with the character `"B"` at the end of this value? I also want to replace the other values without symbol `-` replace with the symbol `"F"` at the end of these values. Like this `-0345` to  `0345B`, `0341` to  `0341F`.

[image]

Comment: What is type of `linecode`, integer or string(text)?

Comment: It's string type

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `regexp_replace` function in field calculator:

[image]

The expression

```
regexp_replace(  "linecode", '^-(.*)$', '\\1B')
```

will replace '-' + 'any string'  with  'any string' + 'B'. So it will change string '-0345' to '0345B'. \\1 refer to the expression part in brackets. You may give more specific regexp instead of '.*'.

[image]

The second expression will add 'F' to numeric strings:

```
regexp_replace( "linecode", '^([0.9][0-9]*)$', '\\1F')
```

It will replace only string made of numeric characters [0.9], so you can use it after the previous expression without selection in the table.

Comment: My answer is easy to understand, but this is more professional. :)

Answer (score 4):

Use this expression: `if(left(linecode, 1) = '-', substr(linecode, 2) + 'B', linecode + 'F')`

I suggest to create new field instead of changing the existing one. You may need the original one later.